# How to use awk to convert field from hexa to decimal

Tags: awk

I am extracting an snmp value that is in hex and I want the output to be in decimal, but i am not able to execute the shell command in awk for field $2 and $4

hex output of the snmp is :

```
00 01 00 30
```

trying to convert using this command:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 10.10.10.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.2272.1.3.3.1.3.206 | awk '{ print 'echo "'ibase=16; $2'|bc"' ; 'echo "'ibase=16; $4'|bc"' }'
```

also tried this

```
| awk '{ print $2, system('echo "ibase=16; $2"|bc') }'
```

but I am not able to get it right

the output should look like :

```
1 48
```

Comment: Which awk are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one for GNU awk:

```
$ echo 00 01 00 30 | gawk  '{print strtonum("0x" $2),strtonum("0x" $4)}'
1 48
```

Here is one for other awks (tested on Busybox awk, mawk and awk-20121220):

```
$ echo 00 01 00 30 | mawk  '{printf "%d %d\n","0x" $2, "0x" $4}'
1 48
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your command outputs like this :

```
[root@instance-1 ~]# cat ggg
00 01 00 30
```

Now run the following command

```
[root@instance-1 ~]# cat ggg | xargs -I {} -d ' ' sh -c 'echo "obase=10; ibase=16; {}" | bc' 

0 1 0 48
```

in the above command replace "cat ggg" with `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 10.10.10.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.2272.1.3.3.1.3.206  .`